# Granger causality test - What dependencies are being captured?

Tags: nonlinear, granger-causality

I'm currently reading on the Granger causality test but different sources seem to be contradicting.

In the original paper [Using the mutual information coefficient to identify lags in nonlinear models](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1994.tb00200.x) (1994) it says:

> An ideal measure of functional dependence for a pair of random variables x, y should [...] (iii) have a value of unity for the modulus of the measure if there is an exact nonlinear relationship between the variables, such as x = h(y).

Now suppose we have the following relationship: $X_t = \lvert Y_{t-1} \rvert$, where $Y_t$ are i.i.d. random variables from a $N(0,1)$ distribution. According to the above definition, the Granger causality should equal 1.

However, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality#Method), Granger causality is calculated via a VAR model and one rejects the null-hypothesis that $Y_t$ does not Granger cause $X_t$ if and only if no lagged values of $Y_t$ are contained in the VAR model. For the example above, one would therefore *not* reject the null hypothesis, even though $X_t$ is completely determined by $Y_{t-1}$.

In essence and to my understanding, this question boils down to whether non-linear effects are captured when testing for Granger causality. Are there maybe different implementations to test for Granger causality, some of which do capture nonlinear effects?

Comment: By *original paper*, you do not mean the paper that proposed Granger causality? (See Granger, C. W. J. (1969). "Investigating Causal Relations by Econometric Models and Cross-spectral Methods". Econometrica. 37 (3): 424–438. doi:10.2307/1912791.)

Comment: I honestly was not aware of this much earlier paper. So the term _original_ might be misleading. I'm referring to the the paper that I linked where a statistic _R_ is defined that can take on values between 0 (two variables are independent) and 1 (two variables are functionally related).

Answer (score 0):

Hi : All Granger causality says is that, if including including a variable X_t as a variable in the forecast for $Y_t$, improves the forecast of $Y_t$, then $X_t$ Granger causes $Y_t$. As far as I know, it's not dependent on the use of a VAR. So my I don't see why  it wouldn't apply to non-linear forecasts also. The point is that it's a very specific type of causality and has nothing to do with  say the causal concept of Judea Pearl. Granger did a lot of work in non-linear modelling so I would confirm this by checking his work in that area out. I think that he may even have a book on non-linear modelling. ( Granger and Lee possibly ? ).

Comment: I completely agree that it should hold for non-linear problems as well. In fact the word non-linear is even in the title of the paper that I linked. But do you agree that as it is described in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality#Method) non-linearity cannot be captured?

Comment: It is worth noting for completeness that (in a two variable system) the history of $X$ needs to improve the prediction of $Y$ *beyond the prediction that uses the history of $Y$ alone*. (I have seen this being omitted and resulting in mistaken interpretations frequently enough to care pointing out.)

Comment: @shiningPanther: I'm reluctant to say that Wikipedia is wrong and then steer you in the wrong direction. If I had time, I'd read 1) or 4) at the bottom of the Wikipedia page carefully but I don't. Maybe the non-linearity  claim is due to the stationarity assumption in Granger Causality. I would think non-linear models would tend to be non-stationary which might rule them out of the GC definition.  I have two books that collect CG's  papers, "Essays in Econometrics", Volumes 1 and Volumes 2. I'll glance through them and see if I find anything that could confirm or unconfirm Wikipedia.